# How do I increase the screen resolution in Cricket 2011 to more than 1024 x 768?

Tags: cricket-2011

I have installed Cricket 2011 (EA Sports) and I find its resolution to be only 1024 x 768. But my screen resolution is 1366 x 768 (15.66" screen), so the game is not running fullscreen.

How can I get it to run fullscreen? I tried to increase the resolution to more than 1024 x 768 in game's display settings but that is already the maximum setting.